# click.TAG from as2 to as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need help to convert AS2 click.TAG to as3. Can anybody help please? :)

as2 code:

```
on (release) {
if (_root.clickthru==undefined&&  _root.clickTag) {
 _root.clickthru = _root.clickTag;
 }
if (_root.clickthru==undefined&&  _root.clickTAG) {
 _root.clickthru = _root.clickTAG;
}
if ( _root.clickTarget ==undefined) {
 _root.clickTarget = "_blank";
}
```

getURL(_root.clickthru, _root.clickTarget);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var clickTag:String = String(paramObj["clickTag"]);

button_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, openBanner, false, 0, true);

function openBanner(event: MouseEvent) : void { 

   flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest( clickTag ), "_blank"); 

}
```